# How to pass, from <input>, a different value that the chosen one

Tags: html, vue.js

I use `<input>` to choose a value in a Vue.js context. The context does not matter (I believe) - this is just to say the value of the `<input>` field is always synchronized with a variable called `searchedName` and that there is no actual "submission" of the input (as it is already available at all times):

```html
<!-- in Vue.js the line reads <input v-model="searchedName" list="foundNames"> and the input content is synchronized with the variable searchedName -->
<input id="searchedName" list="foundNames">
<datalist id="foundNames">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</datalist>
```

When choosing from the dropdown a value, it is this exact string which is chosen (`One` for instance).

I would like, however, this string to just be a display name, and that the actual choice is an Object. As an example, when choosing `One` from the dropdown, I would like to pass further `{"choice": "one", "value": 1, "weather": ["cloudy", "rainy"]}` - and not the string `"One"`.

**Is this possible?**

---

**EDIT**: Just in case, I am posting the actual Vue.js code which handle this bit. `foundNames` is updated somewhere else (in an AJAX call) and is an Array of Objects. The `addID` method is supposed to use `{{name._source}}`, which is currently displayed as it. I would like to hide it and display some of its elements instead.

```
         <label for="something">
            Input "Something": 
            <input v-model="searchedName" list="foundNames">
            <datalist id="foundNames">
                <option v-for="name in foundNames" value="name">{{name._source}}</option>
            </datalist>
        </label>
        <button v-on:click="addID">add name</button>
```

Looking at the first answers, the way to go would be something along the lines of

```
<option v-for="name in foundNames" value="name">{{name._source.interesingelementtodisplay}}</option>
```

but `value="name"` sets the value to `"name"` (verbatim) and not the current value of the variable `name` in the `v-for` iteration.

Comment: Do you have a list of option objects in your Vue that you want to use as the options, or are you hardcoding these values?

Comment: @BertEvans: I added the relevant Vue.js code - please let me know if this is clear

Comment: I added an answer below for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in your edit is close. You need to [bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) the value.

```
<option v-for="name in foundNames" :value="name">{{name._source.interesingelementtodisplay}}</option>
```

or

```
<option v-for="name in foundNames" v-bind:value="name">{{name._source.interesingelementtodisplay}}</option>
```

Note the `:` in front of `value`. If you do not bind it, it will just be the literal value between the quotes, which, as you found, is just `name`.

Comment: Thanks, I slowly start, over several questions, to realize how the binding really works.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just `value` should do the first thing you were looking for.

```
<input id="searchedName" list="foundNames">
<datalist id="foundNames">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once, what I did was something like this

```
<datalist id="foundNames">
  <option value="{'choice': 'one', 'value': 1, 'weather': ['cloudy', 'rainy']}">One</option>
  <option value="{'choice': 'two', 'value': 2, 'weather': ['cloudy', 'rainy']}">Two</option>
  <option value="{'choice': 'three', 'value': 3, 'weather': ['cloudy', 'rainy']}">Three</option>
</datalist>
```

Notice I had to change a little that JSON to use just a single quote, and then to parse it back to JSON I had return to double quote. Nowadays it may be some lib to do that, like this https://github.com/jcoc611/cassandraMAP